# Homework assignment: Hangman

Tags: bash

I'm doing a homework assignment and have to make a working hangman application.
I got most of it working but I want to do something and can't quite figure out how to do it.

What I want to do:
There is a string named `$string`, which contains the random word from a wordlist. When I start hangman i want to display `"*"` for every character in the random word.
Secondly I want to concat the `"*"` with the true character value when it's guessed by the player.

So if the word is "Hello" I want to display `"*****"` and when someone guesses a letter, `"l"`, it will display `"**ll*"`.

What i've tried:

Substring Replacement - http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

tr (in a couple of formats, didn't really understand how to use that, correctly. I tied the `[CHAR*REPEAT]` but keep getting errors)
And searched a lot of websites, but most hits were about concatting 1 specific char not all the chars in the string.

Could you please help me understand?

Comment: Please post your current code, so we can at least have a chance to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

bash's [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) will do:

```
$ string="hello world"
$ guess=""
$ echo "${string//[^[:space:]$guess]/*}"
***** *****

$ guess+="l"
$ echo "${string//[^[:space:]$guess]/*}"
**ll* ***l*

$ guess+="o"
$ echo "${string//[^[:space:]$guess]/*}"
**llo *o*l*
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of guessed characters and your string, you can mask it by telling `tr` to replace everything except the guessed characters, spaces and linefeeds by "*":

```
guessed="etaonris"
string="doing a homework assignment"
masked=$(tr -c "\n $guessed" "*" <<< "$string")
echo "$masked"
```

This gives you `*oin* a *o*e*or* assi*n*ent`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try that tomorrow.
Could you please explain the <<< code?
What does it do? I know << and >> but I don't know <<<.

Comment: <<< is bash specific syntax for piping a string to stdin. It's mostly equivalent to `$(echo "$string" | tr -c "\n $guessed" "*")`